# Call MySQL function in loop

Tags: mysql

I have a Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT assetID, assetName FROM table1;
```

Now I get lets say 5 rows back

```
assetID   assetName 
 101       Name1 
 102       Name2
 103       Name1 
 104       Name1 
 105       Name1
```

Now, I have got a mysql function called GetHealthStatus(INT assetID) which returns 0 or 1 based on health of the asset, Now How can I call that function in loop so that i get result in this format

```
AssetID assetName   Health
 101       Name1     1
 102       Name2     0
 103       Name1     1 
 104       Name1     1
 105       Name1     1
```

Comment: Do you really need DISTINCT or is assetID unique anyway?

The function call part would be 

  `SELECT AssetID, GetHealthStatus(AssetID) AS Health FROM table1;` then ....

Comment: No AssetID is not Unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call a function execution directly from your query, as such:

```
   select AssetId, assetName, GetHealthStatus(AssetId) from table1
```

Comment: It was pretty simple but being new to DB I couldn't figure it out:(

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT assetID, GetHealthStatus(assetID) FROM table1;
```

If you really need the DISTINCT to group your data then:

```
SELECT assetID, GETHealthStatus(assedID) from (SELECT DISTINCT assetID, assetName FROM table1);
```